# Flutter Firebase Firestore List Data Saving Cannot Recall Index as

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, maps

When I'm doing activity from a user in a project, I get the instant location and save it with firebase and firestore. But when I call back the query, I get everything I saved in the list. I just want it to come as an index index. For example 1-"kosum1". How can I do that?

```
dataBaseSave() async {
final User user = auth.currentUser;
await _geolocator
    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
    .then((Position position) {
  setState(() {
    _currentPosition = position;
    GeoFirePoint point = geo.point(
        latitude: position.latitude, longitude: position.longitude);
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Test').add({
      'Liste': FieldValue.arrayUnion(
          [nb1, kosuadi, user.uid, position.latitude, position.longitude])
    });
    nb1++;
  });
});}
```

Data Calling:

```
getData() async {
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Test')
    .where(('Liste'), arrayContains: "kosum1")
    .get()
    .then((value) {
  value.docs.forEach((result) {
   list = result.data();
   var list2 = list.values.toList();
   print(list2);
  });
});}
```

output:

[image]

Firebase Firestore My Collection:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `List` to a `Map` of its index to the list value using the [List.asMap()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/asMap.html) method.

> The map uses the indices of this list as keys and the corresponding objects as values.

Change this part of your code:

```dart
list = result.data();
var list2 = list.values.toList();
print(list2); //[0, kosum1, ...]
```

to this:

```dart
list = result.data();
var map = list.asMap();
print(map);  //[0: 0, 1: kosum1, ...]
```